# Is My Reactjs Components too Granular?

Tags: reactjs

I am playing around with Reactjs and I am wondering if I broken out my components too much.

```
 <script type="text/babel">

class MainCompoent extends React.Component {
      constructor() {
          super();
          this.state = { 
                items : [
                            {
                                name: 'Test 1',
                                type: { value: "1"},
                                types: [
                                          { value: "2"},
                                          { value: "1}
                                      ]
                            },
                            {
                                name: 'Test 2',
                                type: { value: "1"},
                                types: [
                                          { value: "2"},
                                          { value: "1}
                                      ]
                            },
                          ]
                };
      }
      componentDidMount() {
      }
      render() {
          return (
              <div className="item-container"> 
                {
                      this.state.items.map((item, i) => {
                          return <Item item={item} index={i} />
                      })
                }
              </div>
          )
      }
    }

class Item extends React.Component {
      constructor() {
          super();
      }
      componentDidMount() {
      }
      render() {
          return (
              <div className="item"> 
                    <General item={this.props.item} index={this.props.index}  />
                    <Specific1 />
                    <Specific2 />
              </div>
          )
      }
    }

class Specific1 extends React.Component {
      constructor() {
          super();
      }
      componentDidMount() {
      }
      render() {
          return (
              <div className="Specific1-container"> 
                   <h1>Specific1 Container </h1>
              </div>
          )
      }
    }

  class General extends React.Component {
      constructor() {
          super();
      }
      componentDidMount() {
      }
      handleChange(event) {
        this.props.handleChange(event.target.value, this.props.index);
      } 
      handleChange2(event) {
        this.props.handleChange2(event, this.props.index);
      }  
      render() {
          return (
              <div className="general-container"> 
                   <h1>General Container </h1>
                  <div>
                    <label>Name</label>
                    <input type="text" value={this.props.item.name}/>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <label>Type </label>
                    <select value={this.props.item.type.value} onChange={(event) => this.handleChange(event)}>
                        {
                          this.props.item.types.map((type, i) => {
                              return <option key={'type-' + i}  value={type.value} >{type.value}</option>;
                          })
                        }
                    </select>
                  </div>
              </div>
          )
      }
    }


  class Specific2 extends React.Component {
      constructor() {
          super();
      }
      componentDidMount() {
      }
      render() {
          return (
              <div className="specific2-container"> 
                   <h1>Specific2 Container </h1>
              </div>
          )
      }
    }

  ReactDOM.render(<MainCompoent />, document.getElementById("Container"));
 </script>
```

The above code I stripped out everything I don't think was necessary. 
I am trying to do this without flux or redux.

In the Item container, there are 3 components that get rendered together. The general will always be shown but only 1 of the other 2 will ever be shown(despite my similar names they are different and have to be 2 separate components). All 3 components do share properties and hence why I put the state in the top and was passing it down.

The one thing though is when I have to update this state I potentially have to go up 2 parents(ie handelChange from General would have to go up to Item which would have to go to MainComponent to update the state).

Is this bad?

Comment: This isn't bad, but is there a reason you don't want to use flux methods? They're a nice way to keep organized. As far as keeping things flowing efficient and working well you should be fine, but it'll just be harder to organize w/o is all.

Comment: Well I usually use redux myself so never had this issue before but my team is looking how to use reactjs with SalesForce, since my team does not really know reactjs and I don't really know SalesForce, I am trying to stick the basics as seems big harder to get Redux structure into SF.

Comment: Gotcha, you seem to have the right idea then!

Comment: My problem with my solution is, it ok have to bubble up so many times? I wondering if I can somehow cut down on it. kinda sucks that in General I have to pass in the onChange to the Item OnChange then to the MainComponent onChange.

Comment: The only issue I see is that you are passing props back to the parent, e.g.  `this.props.handleChange(event.target.value, this.props.index)`. Why don't you handle that in the parent controller passing directly `event => handleChange(event, index)` to child?

Comment: And no, it's not too granular. In my team we would probably split some of the components even more - into smart and dumb parts.
Don't worry about granularity, components can have one line. Worry about the separation of concerns. Every component should be working independently.

Comment: Well that is my concern as well passing back to the parent over and over again to update the state in my MainComponent. Can you go into more detail how you would solve this. What I am doing is what I saw in a tutorial where you have an event and you basically bubble it back to the parent.

Answer (score 1):

I'd stacked with similar question and found to my self a pretty simple answer. It all depends on what level of abstraction do you need.

Eg. if `Item` component could not "live" without `General` then the better way is to include `General` to `Item`. If they are totally independent then you could simply keep `General props-API` stable and change itself.

Passing props to the parent is OK, but the better way is to keep one `source of truth`. If you don't want to use any of data-flow libraries (redux, flux, whteverx) then simply make the `Root` component as the smartest. Let it to control of app-state changing.

Here is a nice "guide" how to let React components communicate with each other (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lifting-state-up.html). `Parent` to `Child` via Props, `Child` to `Parent` via Callbacks.